# How to iterate json nested entries into google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to iterate the nested "line_items" element from the following json response which gets triggered with a post event into a google sheets spreadsheet using google apps script environment. My goal is to write the elements within each "line_item" into new rows like

[image]

```
{
    "purchaseorder": {
        "**date": "2019-11-27**",
        "submitted_date": "",
        "delivery_address": {
            "zip":"91240"
        },
        "notes": "note",
        "can_send_in_mail": false,
        "template_type_formatted": "Personalizada",
        "documents": [],
        "client_viewed_time": "",
        "discount_amount": 13766.57,
        "discount": "100.00%",
        "taxes": [],
        "billing_address": {
            "zip": "",
            "country": "",
            "address": "",
            "city": "",
            "phone": "",
            "attention": "",
            "street2": "",
            "state": "",
            "fax": ""
        },
        "**line_items**": [
            {
                "bcy_rate": 615,
                "item_total_formatted": "$0.00",
                "line_item_id": "20936000005293043",
                "rate_formatted": "$12,009.14",
                "header_id": "",
                "item_type": "sales_and_purchases",
                "item_type_formatted": "Artículos de venta y compra",
                "description": "",
                "quantity_cancelled": 0,
                "item_order": 0,
                "image_name": "",
                "**rate": 12009.14**,
                "project_id": "",
                "account_name": "Cost of Goods Sold",
                "**sku": "GleRoPeHea**",
                "pricebook_id": "",
                "image_type": "",
                "bcy_rate_formatted": "$615.00",
                "image_document_id": "",
                "**quantity":1**,
                "item_id": "20936000003115919",
                "tax_name": "",
                "item_total": 0,
                "header_name": "",
                "item_custom_fields": [
                    {
                        "customfield_id": "20936000003847163",
                        "show_in_store": false,
                        "show_in_portal": false,
                        "is_active": true,
                        "index": 1,
                        "label": "Color",
                        "show_on_pdf": true,
                        "edit_on_portal": false,
                        "edit_on_store": false,
                        "show_in_all_pdf": true,
                        "**value_formatted": "heather-beige**",
                        "data_type": "string",
                        "placeholder": "cf_20936000003847163",
                        "value": "heather-beige"
                    }
                ],
                "tax_id": "",
                "tags": [],
                "unit": "",
                "account_id": "20936000000656003",
                "tax_type": "tax",
                "**name": "Gome Legion Roof Permanent Heather-Beige**",
                "tax_percentage": 0
            },
            {
                "bcy_rate": 90,
                "item_total_formatted": "$0.00",
                "line_item_id": "20936000005293067",
                "rate_formatted": "$1,757.43",
                "header_id": "",
                "item_type": "sales_and_purchases",
                "item_type_formatted": "Artículos de venta y compra",
                "description": "costo aproximado",
                "quantity_cancelled": 0,
                "item_order": 1,
                "image_name": "",
                "**rate": 1757.43**,
                "project_id": "",
                "account_name": "Cost of Goods Sold",
                "**sku": "GleExSeNat**",
                "pricebook_id": "",
                "image_type": "",
                "bcy_rate_formatted": "$90.00",
                "image_document_id": "",
                "**quantity": 1**,
                "item_id":" 20936000005293057",
                "tax_name": "",
                "item_total": 0,
                "header_name": "",
                "item_custom_fields": [
                    {
                        "customfield_id": "20936000003847163",
                        "show_in_store": false,
                        "show_in_portal": false,
                        "is_active": true,
                        "index": 1,
                        "label": "Color",
                        "show_on_pdf": true,
                        "edit_on_portal": false,
                        "edit_on_store": false,
                        "show_in_all_pdf": true,
                        "**value_formatted": "beige**",
                        "data_type": "string",
                        "placeholder": "cf_20936000003847163",
                        "value": "beige"
                    }
                ],
                "tax_id": "",
                "tags": [],
                "unit": "unit",
                "account_id": "20936000000656003",
                "tax_type": "tax",
                "**name": "Gome Legion Extension semipermanent Natural**",
                "tax_percentage": 0
            }
        ],
        "order_status_formatted": "Borrador",
        "billed_status_formatted": "",
        "order_status": "draft",
        "terms": "Enviar a traves de:\n\nTransportes Coatepec\nCalle Zoquipa 98\nCol. Merced Balbuena\n15810 Ciudad de México, CDMX\n5557641923",
        "can_mark_as_bill": false,
        "contact_category": "",
        "template_type": "custom",
        "color_code": "",
        "contact_persons": [
            "20936000000919055"
        ],
        "has_qty_cancelled": false,
        "sub_total_inclusive_of_tax": 0,
        "created_time": "2019-11-27T16:30:20-0600",
        "delivery_customer_id": "",
        "exchange_rate": 0.051211,
        "is_inclusive_tax": false,
        "approver_id": "",
        "custom_fields": [],
        "submitted_date_formatted": "",
        "ship_via_id": "",
        "vendor_name": "Nomadixgear Manufacturing",
        "status_formatted": "Borrador",
        "reference_number": "INV-562-GleroPeHea + extension",
        "discount_applied_on_amount_formatted": "$13,766.57",
        "price_precision": 2,
        "delivery_date": "",
        "sub_total_inclusive_of_tax_formatted": "$0.00",
        "vendor_id": "20936000000919023",
        "current_sub_status_formatted": "Borrador",
        "approvers_list": [],
        "ship_via": "",
        "adjustment": 0,
        "created_by_id": "20936000000009011",
        "page_height": "11.69in",
        "status": "draft",
        "current_sub_status": "draft",
        "discount_amount_formatted": "$13,766.57",
        "tax_total": 0,
        "delivery_org_address_id": "20936000000903021",
        "billed_status": "",
        "is_viewed_by_client": false,
        "adjustment_formatted": "$0.00",
        "is_discount_before_tax": true,
        "purchaseorder_id": "20936000005293040",
        "attachment_name": "",
        "expected_delivery_date": "",
        "discount_account_id": "20936000000656003",
        "payment_terms": 0,
        "currency_code": "MXN",
        "page_width": "8.27in",
        "sub_statuses": [],
        "total": 0,
        "expected_delivery_date_formatted": "",
        "tax_total_formatted": "$0.00",
        "date_formatted": "27 nov 2019",
        "current_sub_status_id": "",
        "sub_total_formatted": "$0.00",
        "custom_field_hash": {},
        "bills": [],
        "client_viewed_time_formatted": "",
        "salesorders": [],
        "adjustment_description": "Ajuste",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "discount_applied_on_amount": 13766.57,
        "last_modified_time": "2019-11-27T16:46:28-0600",
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "submitted_by": "",
        "submitter_id": "",
        "is_emailed": false,
        "purchaseorder_number": "PO00126",
        "template_name": "Orden de Produccion Nomadixgear",
        "delivery_date_formatted": "",
        "sub_total": 0,
        "attention": "Kareen Kohn",
        "template_id": "20936000004950151",
        "can_mark_as_unbill": false,
        "total_formatted": "$0.00",
        "currency_id": "20936000000015005",
        "payment_terms_label": "Pagadero a la recepción"
    }
}
```

The following code is the best I've come up with after several days cracking my head on it and doesn't do anything. Previously I've been able to write the json to the spreadsheet without iterating with a different code.

```
//this is a function that fires when the webapp receives a POST request
function doPost(e) {    

//Return if null  
if( e == undefined ) {    console.log("no data");    
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("need data");   }    

//spreadsheet data
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet3'); 

//Parse the JSON data  
var event = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);  
var data = event.purchaseorder;

//loop
var rows = [],
      items;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    items = data[i];
    rows.push([data.date, data.line_items]);
  }

//write to sheet 
dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 2);
  dataRange.setValues(rows); 
}
```

Any help to make it work will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is object here; not array.

```
var data = event.purchaseorder;
```

But you are trying to loop over it.
The **line_items is the array over which you need to loop**. So, the for loop will be modified to the following:

```
//loop
...
for (i = 0; i < data.line_items.length; i++) {
    items = data[i];
    rows.push([data.date, data.line_items[i]]);
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I missed that detail, thank you for pointing it out Sunil. Now it writes to the spreadsheet, however it writes two times the first entry, something wrong in the iteration, will keep at it.

Comment: Doesn't look like the issue with `doPost`. However, it might be getting called from someother place as well. Try putting debugger/console.

Comment: I have changed the code to the following and almost have it right, it's just the first value repeating itself.  `//loop
var rows = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.line_items.length; i++) {

    rows.push([data.purchaseorder_number,data.line_items[i].quantity, data.line_items[i].sku,data.line_items[i].description,data.line_items[i].name]);
    
//write to sheet 
var lastRow = Math.max(sheet.getLastRow(),1);  
dataRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow +1 , 1, rows.length, 5);
  dataRange.setValues(rows);
  }`